# Converting RGB to HEX code by consider rgb as a string in java

Tags: android

in my project I try to convert `rgb` value consider as a string to `hex` value  i have tried below code but didn't help a bit..plz.help me.

```
    String myColorString = "rgb(26,33,37)";
    int color = Integer.parseInt(myColorString, 16);
    int r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    int b = (color >> 0) & 0xFF;
    FooterColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```

Comment: Are the RGB values in your string in hex? 26, 33 and 37 - are these hex values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use String Manipulation methods like .subString()
After it use split method. Its simple to use.

```
String colrStr="rgb(12,13,14)";
String tempStr=colrStr.substring(4,11);
String rgbArray[]=tempStr.split(",");
```

Comment: This would break if not all the number have 2 digits

Comment: ok. upto "rgb(" it will not change. So we can do String tempStr=colrStr.substring(4,colrStr.length()-2);

Comment: Using regular expressions would fit better, I guess.

Comment: Yes you can. I jst suggest the other way. Do it where you feel convenient.

Comment: String colrStr="rgb(45, 56, 232)";
        String tempStr=colrStr.substring(4,15);
        String[] rgbArray=tempStr.split(", ");
        int r = Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[0]);
        int g = Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[1]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(rgbArray[2]);
        FooterColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));

Comment: Keep in mind comment of Henry. Its critical point. Do't provide hardcoded end point index in subStringMethod();